# C++ - Segmentation Fault when Inserting in Map or Vector

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, segmentation-fault

So I am inserting a bunch of values into a vector(I tried a map with the same results) and I keep getting segmentation fault on my second vector which is the **VectorMin** . I tried uncommenting that and if I only work with VectorMax it all works great.

For some reason, if I try to manipulate both vectors I will get a segmentation fault. If I uncomment either one, the program loads correctly.

I am using a 3.5mb file with 1000 rows and 362 values for each row.

```
std::vector<float> vectorMax, vectorMin;

void Parser::isMaxMinVector(float value, int index){

    //if the index of the vector is not yet used
    if (index >= vectorMax.size()){
       vectorMax.push_back(value);
    }

    if(index >= vectorMin.size()){
       vectorMin.push_back(value);
    }

    //if new vector is larger, then overwrite it
    //if(vectorMax[index] > value) vectorMax[index] = value;
    //if(vectorMin[index] < value) vectorMin[index] = value;
}


void Parser::parseLine(char* line){
    std::vector<float> vectors;
    char* point;

    char* tk1 = strtok(line, ",");
    char* tk2 = strtok(NULL, ",");

    int i=0;

    if(tk1 == NULL || tk2 == NULL) return;

    float x = strtof(tk1, NULL);
    float y = strtof(tk2, NULL);

    XYPair pair = XYPair(x, y);
    isMaxXY(x,y);

    while(point=strtok(NULL, ",")){
        //convert the token to float
        float f_point = strtof(point, NULL);
        //push the float to the vector
        vectors.push_back(f_point);
        isMaxMinVector(f_point, i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you showed will not be compiled because class std::vector has no member function count.

Comment: Sorry I didn't undo my code far enough. This is my code that compiles just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You several times changed the code of your post. Nevertheless this code snippet

```
if (index >= vectorMax.size()){
    vectorMax[index] = value;
}
```

is invalid because you use non-existent element with index >= size(). I think you meant

```
if ( !vectorMax.empty() && index < vectorMax.size()){
    vectorMax[index] = value;
}
```

Or apply member function resize. For example

```
if (index >= vectorMax.size()){
    vectorMax.resize( index + 1 ); 
    vectorMax[index] = value; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did make changes. What I am trying to do is the following: if the index is out of bounds of the current vector, I want to push the the new value at the index passed to the function. Otherwise, my code bellow that (which I commented out for testing purposes) checks for certain conditions and may or may not override an existing value at a specific index.

Comment: You should use member function resize in this case.

Comment: I did try that already without any success. That is when I tried simply using push_back and that did not work out either.

Comment: I am sorry but you so many times changed the code in your post that i do not understand what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

have you sized the vectors so that they have enough storage allocated to them? IIRC operator[] doesn't resize, its undefined behaviour if there is no value at that element. If you want something sparse, you'll have to use something like a map instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think Vlad from Moscow answer as below is correct.Did it work ?

```
   if (index >= vectorMax.size()){
      vectorMax[index] = value;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't touch the vectors anywhere else, this will work:

```
//if the index of the vector is not yet used
if (index >= vectorMax.size()){
   vectorMax.push_back(value);
   // update index here:
   index = vectorMax.size();
}

if(index >= vectorMin.size()){
   vectorMin.push_back(value);
   // and here:
   index = vectorMax.size();
}
//if new vector is larger, then overwrite it
if(vectorMax[index] > value) vectorMax[index] = value;
if(vectorMin[index] < value) vectorMin[index] = value;
```

The problem about this, however, is that in case of index change `index` value will not be updated. You can change that by using `int &index` in the insertion signature. Vlad's approach is a lot better for that. On the other hand, it's not clear what the other elements in the vectors contain (if you could be creating `vectorMin` artefacts, e.g.).